# Executing an action on a controller in another area in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

So I need to call an action on another controller in another area in .net

Reason being I have some conditional logic to determine whether or not to display something and that is common to my website and mobile version.

So in my mobile site(in a separate area called mobile) I would like to be able to do something like

```
@Html.Action("GetVideoHtml","Service",null)
```

Where Service is a controller in my default area and GetVideoHtml is the action, however again, I am in the mobile area.  I could copy and paste the action into a local action but that seems silly

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying `area = ""` in the route values does the trick:

```
@Html.Action("GetVideoHtml", "Service", new { area = "" })
```

Comment: Actually it's area = ""
you cannot set an anonymous property to null. However you were basically right Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Would anyone like to clarify why this is the case above?

ALSO: This does NOT seem to work if the area is inside another folder IE: ~/shared/Templates/UserTemplates/View_Called You either must link to it directly or move it into a general folder, which might not be ideal