# Call MVC method from Controller Full Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue because I do not know how to call a specific method inside a Controller that is far away on the foler structure. I try to call it this way from my View

@Html.Action("Method", "DesiredControllerName", parameter)

I am pretty sure this works, because I am calling other methods from controllers this way. The only problem is that this time I need to reach a controller that is way up in a different folder, i.e.

The controller is in:
MySolution/Areas/Area1/Controllers/DesiredControllerName

Whereas the CurrentView Im making the call is in:
MySolution/Areas/Area2/Views/Client/CurrentView

How can I make the call work?
Thanks!

EDIT:

I found it,
As the controller is in another Area I just had to add it as a parameter

[The controller for path was not found or does not implement IController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011026/the-controller-for-path-was-not-found-or-does-not-implement-icontroller)

Comment: As long as DesiredControllerName uniquely exist across these two areas it should work as expected. Since @Html.Action will pull the data from route table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing an action on a controller in another area in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695658/executing-an-action-on-a-controller-in-another-area-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you maybe got it, where your example code line:

```
@Html.Action("Method", "DesiredControllerName", parameter)
```

has the 'parameter' parameter, try using an array of anonymously typed routevalues and include an area and controller, something like this:

```
@Html.Action("Method", new { Area = "Area1", Controller =
    "DesiredControllerName", })
```

I am used to using this style of providing mvc routing info using `Html.ActionLink`, but the `Html.Action` should be similar-ish.  here is the msdn page for the [Action method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703423%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Action("Method", "DesiredControllerName", new { Area = "Area1" })
```

This will works